# how to change the input method (ie for a foreign language) in an html text area

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

Assuming that the user's keyboard is set to a US English keyboard setting, is it possible to create an html text box with a button like "Vietnamese" that when clicked, will begin storing all user input as the Vietnamese keyboard input method?

For example, if I couple the button to the [vietnamese-vni input method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VNI), and using my default US English keyboard, I typed: `this is Vietnamese:` then I clicked the button, and typed `tie4ng vie6t`, I want the text area to render `this is Vietnamese: tiẽng viêt`

I wonder if there is a way to do this in html/css/javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not so simple to make your own script, but [there is a library that does exactly what you want](http://www.vntyping.com/):

```js
(function() {
  var txt = document.getElementById('vin'),
      btn = document.getElementById('change'),
      vin = false;
  
  VNTYPING.VNID = ['vin'];
  VNTYPING.SetMethod(0);
  
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    vin = !vin;
    btn.textContent = vin ? 'ENG' : 'VIN';
    VNTYPING.SetMethod(vin ? 1 : 0);
    txt.focus;
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="http://www.vntyping.com/vntyping.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="vin"></textarea>
<button id="change">VIN</button>
```